# How to redirect and return back to same page after a download

Tags: javascript

I  redirected to download page (I used `window.location()` or `window.location.href()` or `replace()`), but after download happens it should again come back to same page. I tried using `setTimeout`, but in vain. Another thing I dont have a chance to write redirect in `download.php`.
Is there any solution for this requirement.
Thanks in advance...
Here is my sample code...

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; URL=index.php">
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
function doSomething(color)
{
//do something nice with params  
document.body.style.background = color;
//alert('Hi......');
/*global window */
/*window.location = 'http://all-free-download.com/free-photos/in_love_cosmos_flower_garden_220378_download.html';*/
window.location.href = 'http://all-free-download.com/free-photos/in_love_cosmos_flower_garden_220378_download.html';
/*return false;*/
//header("location:javascript://history.go(-1)");
window.history.back(-1);
window.onload = function() { setTimeout("redirectPage()",3000); 
/*return false;*/
window.location.replace("http://google.com");
document.body.style.background = red;
window.setTimeout(redirectPage(), 500);
}

function redirectPage(){
window.location='http://google.com';
}

function download(){
var url = 'http://all-free-download.com/free-photos/in_love_cosmos_flower_garden_220378_download.html';
var htm = '<iframe src="' + url +'" onload="downloadComplete()"></iframe>';
document.getElementById('frameDiv').innerHTML = htm;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
This page does call a JavaScript function when the page is loaded, 
without using the onload() event call.

<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
doSomething('blue');
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go back a page (if it was the last page) by doing:

```
history.back();
```

Or store the page URL in sessionStorage (or localStorage) and use `window.location.href()` on the HTML5 web storage variable. If you move through multiple pages.

Although if the page `download.php` is a completely different page out of your control then there is nothing you can do. Once you leave a page, the code on that page is gone, and you can't do anything on other pages (imagine the security issues if you could). In that case your best best would be to just open the download page in a new tab.